# Does Python Regex object have introspection methods/properties?

Tags: python, regex

I'm having a frustrating time smoothing out this code.
I have a zip file containing csv and other file types.
I want to process the csv and exclude what does not suffix with .csv.

I keep getting this error message in one set that only has 1 non-csv file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 41, in <module>
    check = p.search(x).group(0) if (type(p.search(x)) != 'NoneType') else 'None'
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Because I can't check the regex object to see what it is returning I can only go by the error message.
I'm still relatively new to python (6 months) so I don't know if this is a novice mistake or what.

The code:

```
p = re.compile('\.csv')

... processing using ZipFile ...

# prepare selections for csv
check = p.search(x).group(0) if (type(p.search(x)) != 'NoneType') else 'None'

if (check):
    #print(x + " " + str(p.search(x).group()))
    table = p.sub('', x)
    print(" ======= " + table + " ======= ")
    with zf.open(x) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            count = count + 1
            #print(row)
        print(x + " has " + Fore.RED + str(count) + Style.RESET_ALL + " rows of data")
else:
        print(x + " is not a csv file, so not processing.\n")
```

Everything works fine, except the last file, which is a pdf, describing the contents.
It's the last file so I could ignore it, but I'm concerned with the files that may have the non-csv at a higher level in the archive being processed.

I'm concerned with why the logic is giving me trouble with a non-match, when I have given explicit instructions to ignore non-csv files.

Comment: `type(p.search(x)) != 'NoneType'` isn't how you do a None check. The string `'NoneType'` is not a type. If you want to check whether a thing is None, use `thing is None`.

Comment: In general, you cannot use a string that looks like a thing as a substitute for that thing. This is a common thing newbies try, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Also, `'None'` is not equivalent to `None`.

Comment: Any non-empty string in condition gives `True` and `'None'` - is non-empty string. Better to write simply `check = p.search(x)` and then `if (check)`.

Comment: So basically I made all the novice mistakes in one line.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
check = p.search(x).group(0) if (type(p.search(x)) != 'NoneType') else 'None'
```

to

```
check = p.search(x).group(0) if (p.search(x) != None) else None
```

This produces the expected/desired results.

Thanks @user2357112-supports-monica

I mean, I learned the thing that I was doing wrong was wrong, and apparently I forgot.